# Collective pages have two question lists elements with the same ID

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, collectives

On a collective page (e.g.: [Google Cloud](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/google-cloud)), there are two question lists with the same ID.

[image: The DOM view in the developer tools shows two adjacent <div>s with id="question".]

This makes it difficult to select the second question list containing the questions using a userscript, since `getElementById` / `querySelector` returns the first element with that ID.

---

FWIW, I’m developing a new userscript to display more information about questions for frontpage / question lists: [QuestionListsHelper](https://github.com/samliew/SO-mod-userscripts/blob/master/QuestionListsHelper.user.js), and came across this issue.

- Shows you mini image and code previews, post text length count, and how many favourited.
- Comment previews on hover.

[image: Example screenshot of the points above.]

- Shows who hammered or which mod closed the question.

[image: Example screenshot of the points above.]

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out! We will fix this and add an answer to this question when it's fixed :).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thank you for pointing this out. This request has been implemented and there is now only one element with the `questions` ID.